# Which one is a transitive relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I'm trying to figure out which one of these relations are transitive relation(s)

```
{(a,a), (a,b), (b,b), (b,c)}
{(a,a), (a,b), (b,b)}
{(a,a), (a,b), (b,a), (b,b), (c,c)}
{(a,a), (b,c), (c,b)}
```

As I've understood the definition of transitive relation is; if (a,b) and (b,c), then (a,c)

I can't seem to find any (a,c) in any of those relations, would that make none of those transitive relation?

Comment: The statement is not meant to be interpreted literally. The symbols $a,b,c$ in the definition are unrelated to those in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first and last relations are not transitive. Can you see why? You're right that in the first case, since $(a, b), (b, c) \in R$, we'd need $(a,c)\in R$ for the relation to be transitive. $(a, c)\notin R$, so the relation is not transitive.

What's missing in the last relation? We have $(b, c)$ and $(c, b)$ in the relation, so $b\mapsto c \mapsto b$, but $(b, b)\notin R$. Hence, the relation cannot be transitive.

For transitivity, if $(a, b)$ and $(b, c)$ are in the relation, then we must have $(a, c)$ in the relation. But $a, b, c$ need not be distinct. So the problem in the last case isn't about no relation between $a, c$. $a$ is related only to itself, and no other element is related to $a$, so since $(a, a)\in R$, $a$ is "off the hook" here. The problem in the last case is that if it were transitive, then it would be true that $\Big((b, c)\in R \land (c, b)\in R\Big) \implies (b, b) \in R$. It's not, so the relation is not transitive.

Comment: so none of them are transitive?

Comment: The middle two are transitive: no chain of relation is missing.

Comment: Do you know if {(a,a), (a,b), (b,b), (b,c)} is reflexive, symmetric or irreflexive?

Comment: It's not reflexive since $(c, c)\notin R$. It's not symmetric, because $(a,b) \in R$ but $(b, a) \notin R$. Same with $(b, c)\in R$ but $(c, b) \notin R$.